# CSS specificity: Selector with ID doesn't override selector with class?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm not well versed in CSS, but I understand the basic idea of specificity (or so I think). Recently I was trying to override the table CSS of Bootstrap 3, which was defined for each cell like so (this is a partial bit, the part that was effective on the inspected element):

```
.table > tbody > tr.danger > td, .table > tfoot > tr.danger > td {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

I was trying to override the background color of the entire row that contained that cell, with this:

```
table#results > tbody > tr.highlighted {
    background-color: #ffd15b;
}
```

Which, as I understand it, has higher specificity due to the ID. However it wasn't working at all, until I introduced the child `td` in my CSS:

```
table#results > tbody > tr.highlighted > td {
    background-color: #ffd15b;
}
```

Why didn't my first attempt work? I tried in both Safari and Chrome (latest versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not CSS specificity, but merely the background of the cell ( `<td>` ) hiding the background of the row (`<tr>`) behind it.

Comment: So in general does styling on child elements override (or hide) styling on parent elements?

Comment: @BrDaHa - "In general" doesn't apply here. The background of table cells has specific rules, described in [17.5.1 Table layers and transparency](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/tables.html#table-layers) of the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding border-collapse property to the parent table like below
  `table#results { border-collapse: collapse;}`

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work. I'm not sure this really addresses the question, and it's already applied from the bootstrap normalize.less file